infinite loop of code and my application doesn't respond
I recently installed gtk-rs, more specifically version 0.8.2, but when I run the "minimal" code to test it, I get an infinite loop of code (some code is displayed in my terminal) and my application doesn't respond, why?
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{glib, Application, ApplicationWindow, Button};
const APP_ID: &str = "org.gtk_rs.HelloWorld3";

fn main() -> glib::ExitCode {
    // Create a new application
    let app = Application::builder().application_id(APP_ID).build();

    // Connect to "activate" signal of `app`
    app.connect_activate(build_ui);

    // Run the application
    app.run()
}

fn build_ui(app: &Application) {
    // Create a button with label and margins
    let button = Button::builder()
        .label("Press me!")
        .margin_top(12)
        .margin_bottom(12)
        .margin_start(12)
        .margin_end(12)
        .build();

    // Connect to "clicked" signal of `button`
    button.connect_clicked(|button| {
        // Set the label to "Hello World!" after the button has been clicked on
        button.set_label("Hello World!");
    });

    // Create a window
    let window = ApplicationWindow::builder()
        .application(app)
        .title("My GTK App")
        .child(&button)
        .build();

    // Present window
    window.present();
}

I tried app.run() ; but there is an error because of fn main() -> glib::ExitCode

Can you be more specific? An "infinite loop" sounds normal if you just mean the program in the console is still running while the application is open, unless "some code is displayed in my terminal" means you're seeing output that doesn't look right. Does your application show? Is it just the button that's not working?

Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.

If by the below statement

I get an infinite loop of code (some code is displayed in my terminal) and my application doesn't respond,

you mean to say that you only get a window and the button is not shown, make sure you have specified the package name correctly in the Cargo.toml file. The default is GTK+3.
gtk = { version = "0.8.2", package = "gtk4" }

